# Надо ли с PDO использовать mysql_real_escape_string?

Tags: php_pdo, php, mysql

Как я понял, если я использую prepared statements, то функции экранирования типа `mysql_real_escape_string` не надо использовать?

P.S.: с PDO нужно вообще `mysql_*` функции не использовать?

P.P.S.: заодно, вопрос, если я не использую никакой фреймворк, то лучше использовать PDO, чем mysql_* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

функцию mysql_real_escape_string не надо использовать.
Ее использовали, когда текст запроса формируется на php, чтобы вне кавычек ничего не вылезло.
А в подготовленном запросе, схема самого запроса уже создана, осталось только данные подставить, т.е. БД знает что это данные, а не код запроса.

Да, лучше PDO, оно быстрее

Comment: Благодарю!